# Usage of native modules in Fable for a react-native app

Tags: javascript, f#, react-native, fable-f#

I am having some trouble getting javascript code over to an f# fable react-native app. More specifically some react methods to interact with couchbase lite.

Unfortunately my javascript proficiency is non-existant at best, despite this probably being a fairly simple problem. I essentially want this:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

NativeModules.CouchDB.addToDatabase("hei", (err, name) => console.log(err,name));
```

to be used in F# with the fable transpiler, any pointers on how to achieve this would be grand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it will take slightly more work then the code example provided. You essentially have to write bindings in F# for the JS code you want to use. You can find some pointers here: https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html.

You will often need to actually look at the JS code to be able to write correct bindings. For your specific example, you'd implement a CouchDB type with abstract member addToDatabase, like in this piece of code taken from the above link:

```
type IAlert =
  abstract triggerAlert : message:string -> unit
  abstract someString: string
```

Would become: (not working code, just exemplary, I'm not familiar with the CouchDB library)

```
type CouchDB =
  abstract addToDatabase : params -> returnType
```

You'd then actually call the function like this:

```
[<ImportAll("my-module")>]
let mylib: IAlert = jsNative
mylib.addToDatabase params
```